# Render text like Visual Studio Code Interface

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-code, gdi+

I'm trying to render text like the visual studio tabs using C# .NET. Here is an example of what VSCode does:

[image]

Using this code:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.TextContrast = 0;
g.DrawString(someText, Font, someBrush, someArea, new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center});
```

and this font:

```
new Font("Segoe UI", 13, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

I get very close to VSCode. (VSCode uses Segoe WPC, when I looked into the CSS file)

This is my result:

[image]

As you can hopefully see, VSCode's text is just slightly thicker. I've tried Anti-Aliasing with the `TextRenderingHint`, but it looks too blurry with this smaller font. I've also tried `TextRenderer`, but to no avail. Making the font bold doesn't look good either. Is there any way to make this look closer to VSCode? Thanks

Comment: You can use `Microsoft YaHei UI` as Font. The text is drawn using [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext). BTW, when drawing text, you don't need to set `CompositingQuality` (there's no composition), `InterpolationMode` (there's no interpolation), `PixelOffsetMode` is irrelevant (not related to text rendering). `SmoothingMode` is applied to the background. `TextContrast` is better left to the default when `ClearTypeGridFit` is specified. But you won't need any of it.

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much, Jimi. Now it looks just like the VSCode UI.

Comment: Post that as an answer @Jimi!...  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to just use `Microsoft YaHei UI` and `TextRenderer.DrawText`, which was provided by [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi).

Also, the Graphics settings are not needed.
Thanks Jimi!